# What would you call someone that you ask for directions?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm driving around and I stop to ask someone for directions to my destination, is there an English word for that person?

Comment: They'd be acting as a *guide*, though that's too general a word for me to feel completely happy offering it as an answer.

Comment: I was thinking of 'guide' as well as 'local' or 'passerby' but the words don't pertain to helping someone out. Guide fit's but yes it's a bit broad.

Comment: I always say "someone" when I tell my wife that we can stop & she can ask SOMEONE for directions in Chinese or Taiwanese. They're never "guides" & may not be "locals", but they're all "people on the street" or "in a shop". Those random beings that you ask aren't there to help you out, so they don't rate the "Lost-Traveler's Helper-Outer" badge or job title.

Comment: The word for such a person is *helpful*.

Comment: @tchrist: that depends on whether the directions are accurate.

Comment: What do you call them?   “Hey, you!”

Comment: What would you call someone that you ask something of? *accosted*, depending on how nice you are and how introverted they are. Nobody calls them anything until you get to where you're going and have to explain why you're either early or late.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the question does not specify that the person actually be helpful, just someone who is stopped to ask a question of, they could be a ***"bystander"***:

> per [Merriam-Webster Online Dictionary:](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bystander)
>
> ***bystander***: a chance spectator

or more specifically to your question, assuming whomever it is you stopped was on foot, they can be a ***"pedestrian"***

or a ***"pedestrian bystander"*** :-)

Comment: this is probably the closest match. but even a bystander that you don't converse with counts as a bystander.

Answer (score 1):

They could also be called a *guide* if they actually led you to your destination, or to some point closer to your destination.

[guide](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=guide) - a person who advises or shows the way to others

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a specific word for someone who gives directions per se. However, we often use the word *stranger* when talking about someone we approach but have never met before. (We might be asking for directions, or advice about a good place to eat, or some other request, like "Would you take my picture?")

In other words, I could see myself telling a story, and saying:

> We got lost, so we had to ask a stranger for directions.

If the people actually provide good directions, then they could be called *helpful strangers*. If the people are not familiar enough with the area to help out, but they are still courteous, they could be called *polite strangers*. If they are simply rude and unaccommodating, there's a word for that, too – but I'd rather not say that vulgar word here.